# Is the route's name compulsory? - Symfony2

Tags: symfony

Sorry for the stupid question but I was wondering whether the name of the route should be something compulsory or I can call it as I want. Here is an example:

```
# app/config/routing.yml
blog_show:
    pattern:   /blog/{slug}
    defaults:  { _controller: AcmeBlogBundle:Blog:show }
```

I am asking if the name of the route must be **"blog_show"** and if the answer is yes - from where does it come, or I can set it as I want (of course I know that it isn't good to call it purple_butterfly for example, but what about display_blog?).

Comment: yeah, what matters is that it's unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can name it as you want.

Its used to generate Url's, that what you will need it for.

```
$this->generateUrl('blog_show')
```

or:

```
$this->generateUrl('purple_butterfly')
```

Comment: If you use annotation, the name is optionnal. It becomes a underscore separated list representing bundle name controller and method.